# Validation with regular expression and jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I like to make a client-side validation with JavaScript. For this I'm using the jQuery Plugin Validate() watch here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods

By clicking on the submit Button I want to compare the ID inside the iput field with an regular expression. How can I solve this?

For now I did it like this:

```
<form id="checkoutFormBean" action="/view/checkout?execution=e3s1" method="POST">
    <li>
    <input id="id" name="id" class="fieldError required number" tabindex="12" value="" maxlength="2048" type="text">
    </li> 


    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#checkoutFormBean").validate({
                    id: "required",
                    id: {
                        equalTo: "/^2099[0-9]{9}$/"
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
```

But its not working

Comment: You can't have two properties named 'id' in the same object literal. The second one probably just replaces the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After submiting, you just need to use rules to validate.Please have a look into the following url.Here you will get an idea how to specify the rules.

For Example:

```
$("#checkoutFormBean").validate({
   rules: {
     name: {
       required: true,
       equalTo: "/^2099[0-9]{9}$/"
     }
   }
});
```

Hope this helps you :-)

Comment: I just checked it with an right value like 2099123456789 but it says that it's an wrong value !? any hint?

Comment: May be try to mention this and check pattern-match: true. If its not working please find this url for custom rules: http://www.peterotten.com/custom-jquery-validation-rules/